# save a created propertyfile in specific folder

Tags: java, file, properties, save

How can I save a prop file in a specific folder for example,
now it is saved in the root I guess, but it needs to be in the same folder as the class where it is created.

I also want to know how to load it. If it possible to load a properties file easily from the root then it is okay as well to save it in the root.

code creating the file, first 2 lines with // ( = make code work now without using prop file), class name = Providers

```
  public static DataAccessProvider createProvider (URL url) {
    //MovieDAOOnline mdaoOn = new MovieDAOOnline();
    //mdaoOn.setUrl(url);
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("uri", url.toString());
        prop.store(output, null);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return new OnlineProvider();
}
```

code for getting the file, first line in comment needs to be changed to get uri from propertie:

```
    public Movie getMovie(int id) throws DataAccessException{
       //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(url.toString());
       builder.append("movies.xml");
       MovieConfigRead mcr = new MovieConfigRead();
       List<Movie> film = null;
       try {
           film = mcr.geefMovies(builder.toString());
       } catch (JAXBException e) {
           throw new DataAccessException();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           throw new DataAccessException();
       }
       for (Movie movie : film) {
           if (movie.getId() == id) {
               return movie;
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
```

Comment: In 99.99% of the cases, a class doesn't live in a folder. It lives in a jar file (or war file). To store it in a given folder, you create a FileOutputStream or a FileWriter pointing to a file in that folder. What's the problem?

Comment: I added some code, I want to know how I can store the prop file in the folder where the class is where I added the file and secondly I want to load the file in the second lines of code @JBNizet

Comment: What kind of application are you writing (desktop, web, ...)? How will you deploy this application, when it's ready?

Comment: I'm gonna make a zip of my src folder.

Comment: What will an end user do with source files?

Comment: School project and we need to give them a zip containing the src folder and a .pdf with information.

Comment: Then tell them to run the program from the directory where the zip is unzipped, and load/save the properties file from/to that directory, of from/to a known subdirectory, just as you're doing now.

Comment: Isn't there a oneliner code to save the file somewhere?

Comment: Sure: `new FileOutputStream("path/to/somewhere/config.properties")`

Comment: I'm have problems defining the path; my class is located in folder acces, and I want to save it in acces/online/config.properties

Comment: As I said: using the class location as the base to store a file is a really, really bad idea, because in a realistic scenario (i.e. other than an assignment), the class would not be stored in a folder, but in a jar file. And even if it was stored in a folder, you wouldn't store writable data in the same folder as the application classes. You would rather store them in a directory chosen by the user, or in a specific preferences directory of the user home.

Comment: So what I try to do is too difficult, but what I actually want is the url given to the first method to be accessable in different classes, so I thought to save it in a file, but are there other solution to do something like that ?

Comment: Why would you use a file to share information between objects of an application? Store it in memory. What you want to do is not too difficult. It's simply not a good solution, and I don't want to teach you bad solutions.

Comment: I find a solution by reusing my Interface to parse classes with the url; and it works perfectly ;)